# Wordpress - get_search_form() on same line as icons

Tags: php, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I would like to display a few icons on the same line as my search form.  It really wants to be on its own line.  I originally had it added as a form instead of being called through php which worked but I would like it to be more dynamic as you can see.  Is it impossible to do this without adding as a form?

Here is a trimmed down example:

Old way:

```
<div> 
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<form><input type="text"></form>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</div>
```

New way:

```
<div> 
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<?php get_search_form(); ?> 
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see searchform.php and check the styles in style.css for this form.

Answer (score 0):

In my searchform.php there is a  element.

I simply added display:inline; to the form making:

```
<form style="display:inline;">
```

Now everything is displayed on one line.

[image]